# Rewriting URL with query string question mark in htaccess file php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have URL like <kbd>`www.yoursite.com/watch?v=OYQ3svsQ8Ys`</kbd>
and want to redirect it to <kbd>`www.yoursite.com/index.php?v=OYQ3svsQ8Ys`</kbd>

Actually Question mark makes problem
 I am trying :

```
 <ifModule mod_expires.c>  
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^watch$ index.php? [NC,L,QSA]
 </ifModule>
```

Comment: Why did you add the question mark then? What happened without? And why the `[NC]` nocase matching?

Comment: not working without question mark also

Comment: Check the error.log against the access.log, enable the rewritelog else. Get rid of the `<IfModule>` crud. See also [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31280108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error in your file is if content `<ifModule mod_expires.c>`. Change it to `rewrite`

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>  
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^watch$ index.php? [NC,L,QSA]
 </ifModule>
```